# Manipulate pandas.DataFrame with multiple criterias

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

For example I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value_Bucket': [5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10], 
                   'DayofWeek': [1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2], 
                   'Hour_Bucket': [1, 5, 7, 4, 3, 12], 
                   'Values': [1, 1.5, 2, 3, 5, 3]})
```

The actual data set is rather large (5000 rows+). I'm looking to perform functions on 'Values' if the "Value_Bucket" = 5, and for each possible combination of "DayofWeek" and "Hour_Bucket".

Essentially the data will be grouped to a table of 24 rows (Hour_Bucket) and 7 columns (DayofWeek), and each cell is filled with the result of a function (say average for example). I can use a groupby function for 1 criteria, can someone explain how I can group two criteria and tabulate the result in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot tables seem more natural to me than groupby paired with unstack though they do the exact same thing.

```
pd.pivot_table(data=df.query('Value_Bucket == 5'), 
               index='Hour_Bucket', 
               columns='DayofWeek', 
               values='Values', 
               aggfunc='mean',
               fill_value=0)
```

Output

```
DayofWeek      1  3
Hour_Bucket        
1            1.0  0
5            1.5  0
7            0.0  2
```

Answer (score 2):

- `query` to subset
- `groupby`
- `unstack`

---

```
df.query('Value_Bucket == 5').groupby(
    ['Hour_Bucket', 'DayofWeek']).Values.mean().unstack()

DayofWeek      1    3
Hour_Bucket          
1            1.0  NaN
5            1.5  NaN
7            NaN  2.0
```

---

If you want to have zeros instead of `NaN`

```
df.query('Value_Bucket == 5').groupby(
    ['Hour_Bucket', 'DayofWeek']).Values.mean().unstack(fill_value=0)

DayofWeek      1    3
Hour_Bucket          
1            1.0  0.0
5            1.5  0.0
7            0.0  2.0
```